# function is running before sql query is finished, node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

i have made an event listener for my server which listens for when someone is trying to log on, so i do an sql query and then if the info matches, it logs them on. problem is, its testing if the info matches before it runs the query so it will always return false. here is my code

```
player.on('checkLogin', function(data)
{   
    var logIn = "";
    connection.query({
    sql: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", 
    values: [data.user] },


    function(error, results, fields) 
    {                                               
        if (error) 
        { 
            console.log(error); 
        }

        if(results) 
        {   
            var pass = "";  

            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            {
                pass = (results[i].password);
            }

            var input = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data.pass).digest("hex");

            if (pass == input)
            {
                logIn = true;
            }                       
        }
    });

    if (logIn == true)
    {
        this.em.emit('login', 
            {
            id: player.playerid 
            });
    }
}.bind(this));
```

I heard promises will fix this but is there any easy way around this?, thanks in advance

Comment: This question gets asked all the time. You need to reply *inside* the callback. Simply replace `logIn = true;` with whatever code you wanted to run at the bottom.

Comment: i get the error "cannot read property 'emit' of undefined" when it tries to log in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is your `if(login == true)` is outside of the completion handlers of the query.

Move the `if(logIn == true)` into your completion handler.

```
player.on('checkLogin', function(data)
{   
    var logIn = "";
    connection.query({
    sql: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", 
    values: [data.user] },


    function(error, results, fields) 
    {                                               
        if (error) 
        { 
            console.log(error); 
        }

        if(results) 
        {   
            var pass = "";  

            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            {
                pass = (results[i].password);
            }

            var input = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data.pass).digest("hex");

            if (pass == input)
            {
                logIn = true; //<-- could just handle it here.
            }
            if (logIn == true) //<-- moved inside completion handler
            {
               //log on
            }                       
        }
    });


}.bind(this));
```

Now the reason it is being called is your `connection.query` runs asynchronously which is why the `function` handler is used. Code outside the completion handler will be run immediately.

**EDIT from Additional Changes**

Based on your changes your `this` scope will be changed when moved inside the completion handler function. To get a reference back you will need a reference to the `player` scope (assuming that is what `this` is). So that can be handled simply by creating a variable of this as `var that = this;` at the top of your `checklogin` function. Something like:

```
player.on('checkLogin', function(data)
{   
    var that = this; //create a variable to store the scope (this)
    var logIn = "";
    connection.query({
    sql: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", 
    values: [data.user] },


    function(error, results, fields) 
    {                                               
        if (error) 
        { 
            console.log(error); 
        }

        if(results) 
        {   
            var pass = "";  

            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            {
                pass = (results[i].password);
            }

            var input = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data.pass).digest("hex");

            if (pass == input)
            {
                logIn = true; //<-- could just handle it here.
            }
            if (logIn == true) //<-- moved inside completion handler
            {
               //log on
              that.em.emit('login',  //<-- reference `that` not `this`
              {
                 id: player.playerid 
              });
            }                       
        }
    });


}.bind(this));
```

Comment: then i get the error "cannot read property 'emit' of undefined" when it tries to log in

Comment: oh sorry yes ill include it

Comment: @RachelDockter thanks for the update.. I have provided an edit

Comment: Did you at the `var that = this;` at the top?

Comment: i just did and it works now, thankyou very much :):)

Comment: Glad it worked for you.. I would recommend reading up on variable scopes. Cheers